# Почему запрос выводит одну запись?

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(commenttonew.CommentToNewArticleIdNew) AS CNT, new.NewTime, new.IdNew, new.idNew, new.NewPhoto, newcategory.NewCategoryName, new.NewName,

new.NewDescription, CASE WHEN likes.Count IS NULL THEN 0 END AS CountLikes FROM new  
LEFT JOIN newcategory ON newcategory.IdNewCategory = new.idNew 
 INNER JOIN commenttonew ON commenttonew.CommentToNewArticleIdNew = new.idNew 
 LEFT JOIN likes ON (likes.IdNote = new.idNew AND likes.LikeType = 5)  
ORDER BY idNew DESC LIMIT 4
```

Comment: А сколько должен? Может только одна и подходит по условиям?

Comment: Скорей потому, что в таблице `commenttonew` одна запись связанная с `new`, а вы используете INNER JOIN

Comment: Скорей потому, что отсутствует group by и берется одна первая запись.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

[`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/counting-rows.html) - агрегатная функция.

[Агрегатные](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) (групповые) функции выполняют некоторую операцию над группой строк и возвращают вместо этой группы только одну запись - результат своей работы.

Если агрегатная функция вызывается без использования конструкции `GROUP BY`, то группировка ведется по всей таблице. Если же конструкция `GROUP BY` указана, то агрегатная функция вызывается отдельно для каждой группы, у которой значения в столбцах из `GROUP BY` совпадают

Поскольку в вашем запросе есть агрегатная функция `COUNT`, но не указана конструкция `GROUP BY`, то `COUNT` сводит все записи в одну.

Чтобы это исправить, надо либо ввести группировку:

```
SELECT COUNT(commenttonew.CommentToNewArticleIdNew) AS CNT,
...
GROUP BY new.idNew
ORDER BY idNew DESC LIMIT 4
```

либо вывести получение количества в подзапрос:

```
SELECT CNT,
...
(
    SELECT CommentToNewArticleIdNew, COUNT(1)
    FROM commenttonew
    GROUP BY CommentToNewArticleIdNew
) AS commment_count
ON CommentToNewArticleIdNew = new.idNew
...
ORDER BY idNew DESC LIMIT 4
```

либо выбрать нужные вам записи без подсчета количества, а где-то в коде отдельно  запрашивать нужное количество записей через

```
SELECT CommentToNewArticleIdNew, COUNT(1)
FROM commenttonew
WHERE CommentToNewArticleIdNew IN (...)
GROUP BY CommentToNewArticleIdNew
```

Конечное решение зависит от преследуемых целей